# jqvmap - javascript custom code using change url with onregionclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jqvmap

I have the following code for a dropdown of countries. when selected replaces cookie with a new countrycode.:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('select-country').observe('change', function(event){
            countryCode = $('select-country').value;
            onChangeUrl = '<?php echo Mage::helper('switcher')->getCountryUrl();    ?>';
            url = onChangeUrl.replace('%geocode%', countryCode);
            setLocation(url);
            event.stop();
        })
    </script>
```

searching on the internet I found a very good project http://jqvmap.com/. They offer a map and the possibility to trigger a script in order to choose a country. the proposed script code is something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap(
    {
        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: '#555555',
        ...etc.etc....
        onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
            var message = 'You clicked "'
                + region
                + '" which has the code: '
                + code.toUpperCase();

            alert(message);
        }
    });
});
```

my objective is to include the first script into the second one so when I click on a region the script replaces the cookie with the country code, but I have limited knowledge of javascript. any idea would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `onRegionClick`, you can already get the country code by using one of the parameters: `code`.

So putting it altogether:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap(
    {
        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: '#555555',
        ...etc.etc....
        onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
            // here you already got the code
            // use it to save it to your cookies
            onChangeUrl = '<?php echo Mage::helper('switcher')->getCountryUrl();    ?>';
            url = onChangeUrl.replace('%geocode%', code); // --> use code as the country code
            setLocation(url);
            event.stop();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, so working directly with that code inside the {} will work. I have to solve the helper I use to test it, inside jquery gives me an error. i will try to make it work.

Comment: yes working perfect. thank you. Just one question only, if I want to add a redirect to homepage inside the function when user already clicked his-her option, is there any way to do it? thank you!